# How relevant is mathematical optimization today?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

That's it. That's all I'd love to know from you guys. Mathematical optimization, with the aid of today's software. Do you think it's still relevant in today's world?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mathematical optimization is used all over the place. The first example that comes to my mind (just because some papers are lying next to my desk) is controller design for cyberphysical systems. Other examples include all kinds of management things in economy, planning of infrastructure (e.g., location of transport hubs), some areas of software design (e.g., a colleague of mine is designing a real-time scheduler using ILP), experimental design and so on.

Comment: Ah. So it is, indeed, quite relevant. Thanks a bunch! :D

Comment: It's incredibly relevant. The list above is just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Then I'm on the right track. Thanks once again!